# Oboe (AAudio) stream returning ErrorUnavailable on physical devices - Audio device issue?

Tags: android, android-ndk, oboe

Error in question:

```
AAudioStream_requestStart(s#1) returned -889 ---------
AudioEngine: Error starting stream. ErrorUnavailable
```

**UPDATE:** I have narrowed down this problem to physical devices, and there appears to be a condition for it's cause, but I have not found that yet. It happens rarely, so it's tough to pin down. So far I have noticed it to happen on a Pixel 3a and a Galaxy S9+.

I have been having this error occasionally, then It will go away, and I still have not found the solution to it or why it is happening. I have had a couple suspicions, but I have since proven them all false and I'm back to square one.

I have tried reproducing this via:

- Turning on/off bluetooth (worked once, but can't reproduce)
- connecting bluetooth headphones
- connecting plug-in headphones
- all of the above with app in focus, and when another app is loaded

**To solve the issue, all I have to do is restart the physical device.**

My Android Gradle Plugin is `4.0.1`, and Gradle is `6.1.1` NDK Version: `21.0.6113669`

My usage and setting up my audio stream:

```cpp
AudioStreamBuilder builder;
builder.setCallback(this);
builder.setPerformanceMode(PerformanceMode::LowLatency);
builder.setSharingMode(SharingMode::Exclusive);
builder.setChannelCount(mChannelCount);

Result result = builder.openStream(&mStream);

if (result == Result::OK && mStream != nullptr) {
    // Grab stream info

    result = mStream->requestStart();
    if (result != Result::OK) {
        LOGE("AudioEngine: Error starting stream. %s", convertToText(result));
    }

    LOGD("AudioEngine: Starting Stream");
} else {
    LOGE("AudioEngine: Failed to create stream. Error: %s", convertToText(result));
}
```

Debug info:

```
I/AAudio: AAudioStreamBuilder_openStream() called ----------------------------------------
I/AudioStreamBuilder: rate   =      0, channels  = 2, format   = 0, sharing = EX, dir = OUTPUT
I/AudioStreamBuilder: device =      0, sessionId = -1, perfMode = 12, callback: ON with frames = 0
I/AudioStreamBuilder: usage  =      1, contentType = 2, inputPreset = 6, allowedCapturePolicy = 0
D/AudioStreamInternal_Client: open() original HW burst = 48, minMicros = 2000 => SW burst = 96
I/AAudio: AAudioStreamBuilder_openStream() returns 0 = AAUDIO_OK for s#1 ----------------
D/MyApp: AudioEngine: Sample Rate: 48000 FramesPerBurst: 96 BufferSize: 192
D/MyApp: AudioEngine: Channel count: 2 Format: Float Direction: Output
D/MyApp: AudioEngine: Current Buffer Size: 288 BufferCapacity: 3072 SharingMode: Exclusive PerformanceMode: LowLatency
D/AAudio: AAudioStream_requestStart(s#1) called --------------
D/AAudio: AAudioStream_requestStart(s#1) returned -889 ---------
E/MyApp: AudioEngine: Error starting stream. ErrorUnavailable
```

My suspicion is that since I do not programmatically define the playback method (headphones, speakers, bluetooth, etc), this happens occationally, but I currently cannot confirm this or know if this is in fact the issue.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to using Exclusive Sharing Mode. As far as I know, if Exclusive stream is not available, oboe shall provide a Shared stream as a fallback. However, after the Exclusive stream is obtained, I assumed starting that stream shouldn't be a problem. I wonder if there is a possibility of another exclusive stream and there is a restriction that only one exclusive stream can be in started state. This could explain the occasional ErrorUnavailable.

Comment: You could try with Shared for SharingMode and see if this problem appears.

Comment: I was also wondering if the fact that I currently don't close the stream when it's not in use could possibly cause the scenario you describe. Maybe this previous exclusive state persists to the next creation of the activity, and thus prevents itself from starting the stream? I don't know if this is possible though.